# MacBook Pro Fans Won't Turn On

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, temperature

I just bought a refurbished Macbook Pro (Retina, early 2013). It seems to be overheating and shutting down without the fans ever coming on. I first noticed the problem while trying to download a game.

After reading some other answers here, I have downloaded iStat Menus (which helped me confirm that the problem was overheating), I tried resetting the SMC and running the Mac Hardware Diagnostic (no problems reported).

I can use iStat to manually turn on the fans to resolve the problem, but since this is a "new" computer I'd like it to work right out of the box. Even with the fans cranked up to 100% the CPU die is at ~75°C while just downloading a game.

Is there anything else I can try to resolve this issue?

Comment: Honestly if you got the unit from a reputable dealer I would take it back. Refurbished should mean that everything works out of the box.

Comment: You can try a older version of Macs Fan Control https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/47386/macs-fan-control, to kick the fans spin at lower temperature. If I was in your place, I would return it.